# Como le agrego un evento, a estos elementos creados por InnerHTML?

Tags: javascript

Este seria el código que tengo pero no me genera ninguna alerta al momento de hacer click, lo que requiero es que al hacer click en alguno de estos me genera algun evento, he buscado por muchas paginas de internet pero no logro encontrar la respuesta a esto

muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';
fetch(url)
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(datos =>  mostrardatos(datos));


        function mostrardatos (datos) {
            const body = document.querySelector('body')
           

            datos.forEach(pais => {
                const {flags:{svg},name:{common}} = pais;
                    
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.classList.add('card');
                    div.innerHTML = `
                    <h2 class="texto">${common}</h2>
                    <img src="${svg}" class="img" alt="">
                    `;
                    
                    body.appendChild(div);
                   

            });

            var img = document.querySelector('.card');
            console.log(img)
            for(var i; i < img.length; i++){
                img.addEventListener('click', hola)
                }


                function hola(){
                    alert('hola')
                }
            }
```

Comment: Intenta con `img[i].addEventListener...`

Comment: No funciona :·$

Comment: La función `hola` ponla arriba de esa linea. Te muestra algún error la consola?

Comment: querySelector solo deberia traer el primer elemento, intenta con querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `for` no esta bien estructurado y debes usar `querySelectorAll` para que obtenga todos los resultados.

```js
const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';
fetch(url)
  .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
  .then(datos => mostrardatos(datos));


function mostrardatos(datos) {
  const body = document.querySelector('body')


  datos.forEach(pais => {
    const {
      flags: {
        svg
      },
      name: {
        common
      }
    } = pais;

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('card');
    div.innerHTML = `
                    <h2 class="texto">${common}</h2>
                    <img src="${svg}" class="img" alt="">
                    `;

    body.appendChild(div);


  });

  var img = document.querySelectorAll('div.card');

  for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    console.log(img[i])
    img[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert("Presionado")
    })
  }



}
```

## >[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> El método `querySelectorAll()` de un Element devuelve una `NodeList` estática (no viva) que representa una lista de elementos del documento que coinciden con el grupo de selectores indicados.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes toda la razón me hacia falta inicializar la variable `i`